# Xcode Simulator revert to default

Tags: ios, xcode

## What I had done:

I enabled full screen mode on the simulator so I executed the following command:
`defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator AllowFullscreenMode -bool YES`

[image: Simulator]

## Question:

- How can I remove this rectangular bar shown in the image ?

## I have tried the following without any success:

- Executed the above command with a NO
- Deleted `/Users/<Username>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist`
- Created a new Mac User
- Deleted Xcode

Comment: it's related to the new Xcode 11.4 and that is the default, it's not affected by your command

Comment: It is simulator's window titlebar. As for any macOS titled window it is hardly possible to remove one. Why would you need that?

Comment: @MohamedHelmy I thought it was my command which messed it up. Just to confirm your simulator also contains that titlebar ?

Comment: @Asperi I thought my command caused the titlebar to appear, so wanted to revert it. I didn't realise that all Xcode simulators have that.

Comment: yes, I have it too and all people whos have Xcode 11.4 have it :)

Comment: I feel so dumb so sorry to bother you guys.